# File not uploading into the map

Tags: php, html, file-upload

This is my html code:

```
<form action="producttoevoegen.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileUploadForm" id="FileUploadForm">
                            <label for="Upload"></label>
                            <input type="file" name="Upload[]" multiple="multiple" id="Upload" />
                            <input type="submit" name="UploadButton" id="UploadButton" value="Upload" />
                          </form>
```

This is my php code:

```
                    <?php
                            if(isset($_FILES['Upload'])){

                              $UploadName = $_FILES['Upload']['name'];
                              $UploadType = $_FILES['Upload']['type'];
                              $FileSize = $_FILES['Upload']['size'];

                              $UploadName = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#i", "", $UploadName);

                              if(($FileSize > 125000)){

                                die("Error - File too Big");

                              }

                                for($i=0; $i<count($UploadName); $i++) {
                                $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['Upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

                                if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
                                  $newFilePath = /upload/" .  $UploadName[$i];

                                  if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
                            }
                              }
                             }
                            }
```

When I try to upload files it doesn't work. It doesn't show in the map. I've tried a lot of things but nothing worked. Does anyone see the mistake I've made? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You are missing a " before /upload -> $newFilePath = "/upload/" .  $UploadName[$i];

Comment: I tried that aswell but no succes what so ever:/

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_FILES['Upload'])){

    for($i=0; $i<count($UploadName); $i++) {

     $UploadName = $_FILES['Upload']['name'][$i];
     $UploadType = $_FILES['Upload']['type'][$i]; 
     $FileSize = $_FILES['Upload']['size'][$i]; 

     $UploadName = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#i", "", $UploadName);

     if(($FileSize > 125000)){
        die("Error - File too Big");
     }      
     $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['Upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
     if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
      $newFilePath = "/upload/" .  $UploadName[$i]; 
          if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
          }
      }
     }
}
```

Comment: Just tried and didn't work:( no success what so ever :/

Comment: @T.Korkmazyigit updated my code to work with multiple files

Comment: I'm gonna try it on localhost now see if it works that way.

Comment: @T.Korkmazyigit let me know the result

Comment: Okay thanks, I've tried for now still not working I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: update line $newFilePath = "/upload/" .  $UploadName;

Answer (score 0):

Please find updated code

```
<form action="producttoevoegen.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileUploadForm" id="FileUploadForm">
                            <label for="Upload"></label>
                            <input type="file" name="Upload" multiple="multiple" id="Upload" />
                            <input type="submit" name="UploadButton" id="UploadButton" value="Upload" />
                          </form>
```

Use this code for PHP script which is given by @Minesh Patel

```
if(isset($_FILES['Upload'])){

    for($i=0; $i<count($UploadName); $i++) {

     $UploadName = $_FILES['Upload']['name'][$i];
     $UploadType = $_FILES['Upload']['type'][$i]; 
     $FileSize = $_FILES['Upload']['size'][$i]; 

     $UploadName = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#i", "", $UploadName);

     if(($FileSize > 125000)){
        die("Error - File too Big");
     }      
     $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['Upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
     if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
      $newFilePath = "/upload/" .  $UploadName[$i]; 
          if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
          }
      }
     }
}
```